# How to create window service to read the xml file

Tags: c#, sql, xml

i have to create window service which read the xml file and and take the node's value to connect the sql server and create the log file i have already created window application for that but i don't know how to create win services.

Answer (score 1):

> but i don't know how to create win services.

In Visual Studio Pro and above:

File => New Project => Visual C# => Windows => Windows Service

and see the [walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) or [howto here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9.aspx).

The most important thing is that during the service startup you *only* do things like spawn a worker thread. You don't do the real processing in there (otherwise it will timeout when starting the service, and Windows will kill it). Oh, and check what working-folder the service starts with - you might find it is the system folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at TopShelf (http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/), which is as described by their website:

"Topshelf is a lightweight framework for building Windows services using the .NET framework. The key goal of Topshelf is limiting the surface area of service-related code within the application."

It might save you some time when it comes to simplifying the development and deployment of your service.